# getting php/html form exactly the same in email on filled in

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a form online php/html that has 74 entries.
and there are 70 entries that have radio buttons with 3 options.

When i fill it in and send it to my email. I get a 2 nice koloms with in 1 the questions and the other the answers or clicked radio buttons.

Is it a simple task to get it in my email like the form (www.lubke.nl/form/index.php)
is filled in.
So i also see the not chosen radio buttons.

Like a copie of the form only filled in from the web.
Thats the idea..

Comment: are you using php's mail(); function?

Comment: yes i am, i need to have the filled in webform exactly the same in the mailbox.

Comment: You can't get the filled in inputs directly, but you know what the source is - the PHP created it itself - and then all you need to do is set the checked ones (from the posted response) and mail that.